# Is there a way to find the distribution of a random value if you know it's relation to other random values you do know the distributions of?

Tags: probability

Sorry if the question sounds unclear. Here's an example of what I mean: say you have a number of simple circuits with one resistor. The voltages of the circuit are continuously normally distributed with a mean and a standard deviation you know, and the resistances are discretely uniformly distributed with a min and a max you know.  Current is of course equal to $\frac{V}{R}$ and you need to know how the current is distributed. We're learning how to simulate these kinds of situations in a Computer Problem Solving in Engineering class using Monte Carlo simulation, by creating thousands of pairs of random $V$s and $R$s, calculating the corresponding currents, and plotting them on a histogram.

But I was wondering if there's a way to calculate the distribution curve of the current from the distribution curves of $V$ and $R$. Or in general, if you have a set of random variables $a, b, c, . . .$ and you know their distributions, how (if at all possible) do you find the distribution of a variable $x = f(a, b, c, . . .)$?

Comment: If the distributions of two random variables $V$ and $R$ are available, yes, the distribution of $I=V/R$ can be derived deductively. This a typical example of a major topic of probability theory, often referred to as **functions of random variables**.

Comment: The comment above is right. As an addition, in practice, the reason you're probably required to use Monte Carlo is because the distributions are ugly enough to make the mathematically explicit solution a pain to find. There many not even be a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the voltage (denoted by $V$) is a random variable (RV) of (approximate) normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and the resistor (denoted by $R$) is a discrete RV of uniform distribution, $P_R=\frac{1}{n}$ for $r_i$, $i=1, 2, ..., n$. Denote the current by $Z=V/R$. The CDF of $Z$ is the probability that $Z\leq z$, i.e.,

$P(Z\leq z)=P(V\leq zr)=\frac{1}{n\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^{zr_i}e^{-\frac{(v-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dv$.

The pdf of the current $Z$ then is

$f_Z(z)=\frac{dP(Z\leq z)}{dz}=\frac{1}{n\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{i=1}^n r_i e^{-\frac{(zr_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$.

It can be verified that $\int_0^\infty f_Z(z) dz=1$ as it should be.